# FileFilter for JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filefilter

I want to restrict a `JFileChooser` to select only mp3 files. But, the following code allows all file types:

```
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MP3 File","mp3");
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```

Comment: Did not try, but according to the [Javadoc for the constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html#FileNameExtensionFilter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29), the first parameter is just the name of the filter; accepted extensions start with parameter no. two.

Comment: I tried that too, but it do not works!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try and use `fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter)` instead of `fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);`

Answer (score 20):

If you want only mp3 files:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class SalutonFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MPEG3 songs", "mp3");
        fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: finally some solution that actually works for me - upvoted, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("My mp3 description", "mp3");
```

The first argument is simply a description of the `FileNameExtensionFilter` - and since the second argument is var args, you can leave it out like you did, effectively meaning there is no filter.

Answer (score 4):

`fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter)` will add a custom file filter to the list of user-choosable filters. By default, the list of user-choosable filters includes the *Accept All filter, which enables the user to see all non-hidden files*.

You will need to invoke: `fileFilter.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false)`

The `setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(boolean)` determines whether the AcceptAll FileFilter is used as an available choice in the choosable filter list. **If `false`**, the AcceptAll file filter is removed from the list of available file filters. **If `true`**, the AcceptAll file filter will become the the actively used file filter.

Comment: Thank you ! Just a remark: setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed() belong to the JFileChooser class ;)

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet may help you:

```
JFileChooser jfc=new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir","."));

FileFilter ff = new FileFilter(){
    public boolean accept(File f){
        if(f.isDirectory()) return true;
        else if(f.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) return true;
            else return false;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return "MP3 files";
    }
};

jfc.removeChoosableFileFilter(jfc.getAcceptAllFileFilter());
jfc.setFileFilter(ff);

if(jfc.showDialog(frame,"openG")==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        String fileName = jfc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
}
```

Comment: This functionality is already build in with the 'FileNameExtensonFilter' class...