# (Java) FileChooser only allow specific file?

Tags: java, file, filechooser

How is it possible to allow the user only to open a specific file?

In my case I want only to allow to open the `"myapplication.exe"` file, which could be somewhere on my filesystem, so this is why I need the `FileChooser`.

I only know how to allow specific file extensions.  I could only allow them to open all `*.exe` files, but this is too much; I only want to allow this one specific file.

I searched so much, but did not find a solution to this.  I hope you could help me.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411919/filefilter-for-jfilechooser

Comment: Corrected the grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any implementation of [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) to the file chooser, it does not have to be a FileNameExtensionFilter