# using a jfile chooser to get path of a exe file

Tags: java, jfilechooser

```
JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
System.out.println("You chose to open this directory: " +
filechooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

this is  the code i used to `open a file` and get its `path printed` but the thing is i want to get the `path of a exe` file which means path should end up with the file extension at the end. with the  current code it won't even show the `exe files.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need exe files, you can use a Filter, but with the good options, like that (your code is Directories oriented ):

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("EXE File","exe");
filechooser.setFileFilter(filter);
filechooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println("YOU CHOOSE "+file.getAbsolutePath());
```

a usefull link on that question: [FileFilter for JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411919/filefilter-for-jfilechooser)

see this for the option filechooser.setFileSelectionMode:

[JFileChooser select directory but show files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883447/jfilechooser-select-directory-but-show-files)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't show files, you're using

```
filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

Comment: then what should  i use

Comment: Just remove the line completely